# RxJava combine/merge object with list

Tags: rx-java

I have 2 observables, one returns 1 element and the other one returns multiple elements.
My goal is to merge them together, **without blocking**, to build an object like this :

```
class Combined {
    Server server;
    List<Client> client;
}

Observable<Server> server = getServerById("1"); //returns an observable of 1 server
Observable<Client> clients = getClientsByServerId("1"); //returns an observable of 0 to n clients

Observable<Combined> combined = //...
```

I tried zip, merge and combine, none of them seems to be the solution.

Comment: why not `Observable.just(new Combined(s, listOfClients))` ?

Comment: I don't have the (s) and (listOfClients). to simplify I wrote this but in reality they both are database calls. I have updated the question to avoid confusion

Comment: what you mean by **whitout blocking** ? it means that server or client can be null inside the `Combined` object ?

Comment: can you add the result of what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` should work, provided `getClientsByServerId` is finite:

```java
Single<Combined> = Single.zip(
    server.singleOrError(),
    clients.toList(),
    (svr, list) -> new Combined(svr, list)
)
```